# Table format in email body using Java program

Tags: java, email, html-table, buffer, bufferedreader

Experts,

I am exploring in java to write email with body content which contains image and a table content.

I have tried the code to add table in the body content.

1. I have table format but the border is not working. the table looks blank without border. I have given the code below can you please check and advise what I am missing.
2. Need to attach the image in the body content , image is in the local.
3. table content + image in the body. I am writing this code in the custom method.how can i return these 2 to the main method using this custom method .

sb.append("");
        sb.append(
                " p{ width: 450px; } .Completed{ color: GREEN; } .Warning{ color: ORANGE; } .Error{ color: RED;} td{ style='padding:1 30 1 30'; border:100 !important; } ");

```
    if (recorder.getNumOfErrors() > 0)
    {
        sb.append("<p style='color: RED;'>Number of failed steps : " + recorder.getNumOfErrors() + "</p>");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.append("<p>Number of failed steps : 0</p>");
    }

    sb.append("<p>Total count!!!: " + recorder.getTotalTime() + "</p>");

    sb.append("<table style=\"border:\"300\"; cellspacing=\"0\"; cellpadding=\"10\">");
    sb.append("<tr>");
    sb.append("<th>");
    sb.append("<td>");
    sb.append("ID");
    sb.append("</td>");
    sb.append("</th>");
    sb.append("<th>");
    sb.append("<td>");
    sb.append("Status");
    sb.append("</td>");
    sb.append("</th>");
    sb.append("<th>");
    sb.append("<td>");
    sb.append("Command");
    sb.append("</td>");
    sb.append("</th>");
    sb.append("<th>");
    sb.append("Time");
    sb.append("</th>");



    sb.append("</tr>");

    int mCount = 0;


    sb.append("</table>");

    sb.append("</BODY></HTML>");
```

table is working, but not the border. and how to add image to the same body and return these 2 to main method.